# Image picked from gallery on Android device throws "no such file or directory" when saving to online storage

Tags: android, react-native, amazon-s3, android-image

In my React Native 0.66 app, there is a function saving images to online storage service OSS. Here is the code for saving to OSS:

```
import AliyunOSS from 'aliyun-oss-react-native';
AliyunOSS.initWithSecurityToken(STSConfig.SecurityToken,STSConfig.AccessKeyId,STSConfig.SecretKeyId,endPoint,configuration); 

const saveOSS = async (bucket_name, objkey, filePath) => {
        return (new Promise((resolve) => {
            AliyunOSS.asyncUpload(bucket_name, objkey, filePath).then( async (res) => {
                resolve(true);
            }).catch(async (error)=>{
                //==<< no such file/directory was thrown. see error image
                setTimeout(()=> {
                    AliyunOSS.asyncUpload(bucket_name, objkey, filePath).then( async (res) => {
                        //console.log("Success : ", res);
                        resolve(true);
                    }).catch(async (error)=>{
                        resolve(false);
                    })
                }, 20);
            })
        }));
    };
...
//<<== filePath returned below is from response out of [image crop picker][1]. 
//It is a cache path. see image below for detail
res = await saveOSS(bucket_name, objkey, filePath);  //<<==
```

[image]

After image was picked (displayed on device), saving it to online OSS throws error in `saveOSS` on device (One is Android 10. Another device's version not known). Except the image name, the path in error is not exactly the same as the path passed in:

[image]

The code above works in dev but not on real android device. How to fix this error of image file not found?

UPDATE:
tried 2 image pickers: react-native-image-picker and react-native-image-crop-picker. The error is the same for both on real device. I guess the issue may not be image picker related.

Also here is the permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: does those environment variable resolve? Did you try printing them?

Comment: The problem seems to be the (file) path from image picker and the path is a cache location. `saveOSS` returns error of file not found

Comment: You probably want to show your code on imagepicker, or look for similar problem with imagepicker on stackoverflow, since your question has now changed.

Comment: Please explain how a file that resides in /data/user/.... suddendly lands in /storage/emulated/.... Why didn't you comment on this? You also should put the values for the variables in your post. Starting with  async (bucket_name, objkey, filePath)  as we now have to guess what you do.

Comment: Further you should use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you try to upload a file.

Comment: `Image picked from gallery....` Nothing in your code has anything top do with picking an image from galery. Pretty confusing post.

Answer (score 1):

- android device build version?
- did you app granted the SD card read/write permission?
- The shareed URL which start with "file://" does not work in Android N（may be） and above（throw security exception.）
- Could u please check the absolution path in command line? like below:

  `adb shell ls -al /path/to/your/image.png`

Comment: Hi coopeng, one device is Huawei p30 with android 10. another device's version is not known. The image path presented in message above are cache path after the image was picked up by image picker. I am not sure if checking outside of the app is doable

Comment: when app runs on emulator, the filePath (start with file:///)was copied into browser and the image was displayed successfully.

Comment: understood，in fact, the filepath which start with "file://" is parse from absolutepath to uri, and “file” is the schame of the uri.

Comment: now, I think, you should to check the full logcat to filter the security exception. of course, dont forget to check the source code of `AliyunOSS.asyncUpload`

Comment: What I am afraid is that the problem is with ALiyunOSS.asyncUpload as this module was pretty much abandoned. I checked the source code (not familiar with java) and was not able to find something suspicious. it calls a native java module to upload. I am not sure if android permission plays a role here. What I have eliminated is that it is not an issue with the image picker used (tested with 2 commonly used image pickers. both has the same error).

Comment: Also removed `file://` at the beginning of the filePath and pass the rest to OSS. The error is the same on real device. But it seems working on emulator. Android emulator seems very forgiving but not the real device.